# Can one TS module modify the import of another?

Tags: typescript

We have a TS `module A`, and another `module B` that is a plugin for `module A`.

`Module A` declares:

```
interface foo {
  key: string;
  key2: string;
}
```

And we're trying to do, in `module B`:

```
declare module "A" {
  interface foo {
    key3: string;
  }  
}
```

If we do this instead in the root project, it works, but it doesn't seem to be working as structured here (`module B` modifying `module A`).  My hunch is that TS is preventing scope leaks here.  Can anyone confirm whether or not this is possible?  If it's not possible, can anyone suggest a pattern that would work well?